# Limit point of a complex sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

maybe someone can give me some advice on how to show that?

**Problem**: Show that $y ∈ C$ is a limit point of $(y_{n})_{n∈N}$ (complex sequence) exactly when, for any $ε$ > 0, there are infinitely many sequence members in the $ε$-neighbourhood$$U_{ε}(y) := {x ∈ C | |x - y| < ε}$$ of y.

**Thoughts on that**: Then, for each $n$, there ist an $x$ different from $y$, which lies in the $\frac1n$ - neighbourhood of $y$. I have to choose such a one as $x_{n}$. Then the sequence of $x_{n}$ is a subsequence converging to $y$ subsequence of $y_{n}$. Am I on the right way?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right way.

Answer (score 1):

A subsequence of $(y_n)$ is a sequence $(x_n) = (y_{\varphi(n)})$ where $\varphi : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is *strictly increasing*. You have to adapt your argument a little bit to make sure this is the case of the sequence you are building.

Then, you also have to prove the converse statement : if $y$ is a limit point of $(y_n)$ then for any $\varepsilon >0,\ldots$